# Cognos 10.2.2Stitching of Burst Outputs

Tags: pdf, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

we have cognos report which is running with bursting as "yes" and give close to 70 outputs. we get 70 different PDF files but my requirement is to get 1 PDF file with 70 pages(all burst outputs).

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a little more details about what you have done, please post a [mcve]

Comment: Report is Giving 70 different PDF files but I want all outputs in 1 PDF files. please let me know what more details are required here.

Comment: The way that it decides how to divide up data is based on the way your burst is setup.  To give you the correct setup, we will need at a minimum the settings in your 'Burst Options'.  Also, do you have a query associated with your report pages, and is that being fed from the queries involved in your Burst options?

Comment: Bursting is happening as per the data available in burst table. Report pages have queries associated and we have created master detail relationship between burst and query to fetch data as per burst group codes available in burst table.

Answer (score 1):

Turn bursting off, disable any unneeded filters, and create a Section based on the data element (Store, Region, etc.) you want to filter per page. Then add a Page Break to the top of the Section.

Bursting is for sending different data to different people based on their permissions, group memberships, etc.